# Getting the overall retweet_count of an account using Twitter API

Tags: twitter

Can we get the total **Retweet_Count** per an **account** OR per **Screenname** like followers count at user level as followers count is a property associated with user information, Where as **Retweet_Count** is a field associated with each individual Tweet. 
I'm thinking I need to get all the tweets of a user then add the filed Retweet_Count in each & every tweet a user received. Here the problem is the total number of tweets getting using twitter rest api are limited to last ***200*** tweets (***only 2 weeks*** old tweets in these ***200***).

We cannot find historical tweets with **Streaming API**, If we store all the **real time tweets** using **streaming api** in our **local database** then with the **use of id** of each tweet record in our local data base we need to call **twitter rest api** call(**GET statuses/show/:id**) in a ***loop***, then add all the **Retweet_Count** value in this loop. But due to this the number of restapi calls are increasing to get the total Retweet_Count.

Please suggest me for the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not at all possible .

Since the `retweet_count` associates with each `tweet`, you need to get all the tweets first.

The reason why i said it's impossible is because **if a user has more than 3200 tweets**, then you can't get the exact retweet_count as **twitter offers only 3200 most recent tweets of a user** through `GET statuses/user_timeline`.

> GET statuses/user_timeline method can only return up to 3,200 of a
>   user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the
>   user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is
>   set to false when requesting this resource.

One more thing. Some Tweets `retweent_count` may vary time to time. I mean some may undo retweet & some may retweet old tweet or past week tweet. So, you need to retrieve all the tweets again and again to update-to-date with exact `retweet_count`. By doing this, there are more chances that you will fall in `Twitter's Rate Limit`.

Comment: Thank you Raj, you mentioned as we only get the recent 3200 tweets only, Is the rest api call **GET statuses/show/:id** provide the oldest tweet If we provide ID of the oldest tweet that is older than 3200? Inorder to display the Retweet_Count & mentions_Count of a user in any of our local project, Is it not possible for us.

Comment: @Prabha Yes, you can get. But, think how will you get those ID? If you use any other API to get ID, then there comes the rate limit. Also if an user have 4000 tweets, then you need to recall again and again to up-to-date with the exact retweet_count and mention_count. You can try yourself but i'm sure this can't be done because of Rate limit , tweets availability and the performance issue.